# Interaction between Files App and my App's document folder

Tags: ios

My App writes files to its document folder using the FileManager class with the path for my App specific document folder.

I can later find these files using the FileManager and this path.

> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/ ... GUID ...
>   /Documents

When I copy/paste files (Directory Tree) from some other (Cloud) source into my document Folder I can see these and navigate these files using the IOS Files App.

But when I run my app and try to use the FileManager class to find these files, it only finds the files that were explicitly written by my app.

So where are my files ? What do I need to do to be able to access these files (The files are an arbitrary tree of files with a variety of file types) ? I would like a unified interface that can navigate the files that I wrote as well as the files that the user copied into my documents directory.

Comment: Are you using a real device or simulator ? If real device, which version of iOS ?

Comment: Real IPad - IOS 12

Comment: OK, iOS10.3.1/2 has issue(?) w/ file name encoding due to new file system. But that's not for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that my app was using the Documents Directory from a Group container.
And the Files App was using the Documents Directory of my App.
I found this by inspecting my App container using the techniques described in
[IOS Storage Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/204/)